# Wordpress Database importing giving strange error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I exported the database of a Wordpress. So far so good. But when i tried to import it through PHPMyAdmin from a cPanel i started receiving the following error:

> INSERT INTO wp_commentmeta VALUES (
>
> "1",  "1",  "_wp_trash_meta_status",  "1" );
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine

I tried changing the browser, the host, exporting the database through different modules. Nothing worked.

I also tried fixing the database using the 'repair' function available in the cPanel but it didn't worked as i got this in response:

> [projamz1_pds.wp_commentmeta] note: The storage engine for the table
> doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_comments] note: The storage
> engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_layerslider] note: The storage engine for the table
> doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_links] note: The storage
> engine for the table doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_options]
> note: The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_popover_ip_cache] note: The storage engine for the
> table doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_postmeta] note: The
> storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_posts] note: The storage engine for the table doesn't
> support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_revslider_css] note: The storage
> engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_revslider_layer_animations] note: The storage engine
> for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_revslider_settings] note: The storage engine for the
> table doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_revslider_sliders] note:
> The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_revslider_slides] note: The storage engine for the
> table doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_revslider_static_slides]
> note: The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_term_relationships] note: The storage engine for the
> table doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_term_taxonomy] note: The
> storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> [projamz1_pds.wp_terms] note: The storage engine for the table doesn't
> support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_usermeta] note: The storage engine for
> the table doesn't support repair [projamz1_pds.wp_users] note: The
> storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

The code that i suppose is the core of the problem is:

> INSERT INTO `wp_commentmeta` (`meta_id`, `comment_id`, `meta_key`,
> `meta_value`) VALUES (1, 1, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (2, 1,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (3, 18, '_wp_trash_meta_status',
> '0'), (4, 18, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (5, 34,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (6, 34, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (7, 33, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (8, 33,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (9, 10, '_wp_trash_meta_status',
> '0'), (10, 10, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (11, 9,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (12, 9, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (13, 19, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (14, 19,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (15, 23,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (16, 23, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (17, 22, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (18, 22,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (19, 32,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (20, 32, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (21, 31, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (22, 31,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (23, 3, '_wp_trash_meta_status',
> '0'), (24, 3, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (25, 30,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (26, 30, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (27, 29, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (28, 29,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (29, 28,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (30, 28, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (31, 15, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (32, 15,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (33, 27,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (34, 27, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (35, 26, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (36, 26,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (37, 2, '_wp_trash_meta_status',
> '0'), (38, 2, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058099'), (39, 25,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (40, 25, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058099'), (41, 24, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0'), (42, 24,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (43, 8, '_wp_trash_meta_status',
> '1'), (44, 8, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (45, 7,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (46, 7, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058104'), (47, 6, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (48, 6,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (49, 5, '_wp_trash_meta_status',
> '1'), (50, 5, '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (51, 4,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (52, 4, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058104'), (53, 11, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (54, 11,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (55, 14,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (56, 14, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058104'), (57, 13, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (58, 13,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (59, 12,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (60, 12, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058104'), (61, 17, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (62, 17,
> '_wp_trash_meta_time', '1425058104'), (63, 16,
> '_wp_trash_meta_status', '1'), (64, 16, '_wp_trash_meta_time',
> '1425058104');

Tho' i did not wanted to delete it and import like that because i am afraid i will break something.

Any suggestions?

LE: I tried importing without the part i suspected being the problem. Without success. Still the same error - #1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine . But now i got 2 tables imported instead of one. Still cannot figure out the problem. As the wordpress is working without any kind of problem. I think something happens when i try to export the database.

Cheers

Comment: My guess is that it's apermissions issue

Comment: Like, i do not have permissions to export? But it's my host. Should i make a ticket? The problem is that i'll get an answer in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cheap and nasty shared hosting providers don't support all the MySQL access methods.

Try this:  For each table find the part of the SQL file generated by your export that looks like this, for example.

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
    `option_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `option_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `option_value` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `autoload` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
    PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `option_name` (`option_name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Delete the line saying `ENGINE=something`, and retry your import. That will allow the MySQL server to use whatever ENGINE it has available.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, i managed to solve my issue using your solution :)